# EntityFramework Core Database.EnsureCreated doesn't create database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I create a project with dotnetcore and entity framework core. I use MySql database and I added dependency to `SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` version `7.1.19`.

I created a `SeedData` class where initialize my database:

```
public class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>())) {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}
```

The call to seed class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Other code

    SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
}
```

And the configuration of service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other code

    // Add database
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => {
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });

    services.AddScoped<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptions, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>();
}
```

When I start the project I get an exception on `EnsureCreate` call. Exception message say `Authentication failed` but if I manually create database (without tables) my connection string works fine and `EnsureCreated` simply create tables for my entities.

What's wrong? It's a problem with `SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`?

Comment: erikscandola, have you solved that?

Comment: @JohnSmith, not yet

Comment: @erikscandola Do you have a empty database is exists?

Comment: @bravohex I have no database

Comment: I think you should create empty database in mysql first. Then use ef code-first to update-database

Comment: @bravohex Yes. This is what I actually do, but it should create database itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem you described. It looks like the SapientGuardian provider might simply have an incomplete implementation in this version.

The SapientGuardian project's [readme file](https://github.com/SapientGuardian/SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/README.md) actually suggests using a more actively maintained provider such as [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). So I switched my project to Pomelo. Now the call to EnsureCreated creates the database as expected and does not have an authentication failed exception.